# What is the form id used in user profile edit form?

Tags: 8, forms

I'm trying to alter some fields in the user profile form but I'm not sure why the form_id **user-form** is not working.

What I'm trying to achieve is to bring back the REQUIRED status of the password field which I turned off in user register form.

```
//USER REGISTER FORM
function MYMODULE_form_user_register_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, 
$form_id) { 
$userID = \Drupal::currentUser();
$userRole = $userID->getRoles();
if($userRole[1] == 'ROLETOCATCH'){
$form['account']['pass']['#required'] = FALSE;
$form['account']['mail']['#required'] = TRUE;
$form['account']['roles']['campaign_manager']['#default_value'] =  TRUE;
$form['account']['notify']['#default_value'] = TRUE;
}   
}

//USER FORM UPDATE
function MYMODULE_form_user_form_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, 
$form_id) {
    kint('hello');
}
```

Comment: form ID for user edit form: user_profile_form

Comment: Still not working, I've tried this before.

Comment: In D8, the 'user_profile_form' is now call 'user_form'. Then to use it directly with the hook_form_alter(), you must use 'MYMODULE_form_user_form_alter'. On your code you have MYMODULE_form_user_form_form_alter.

Answer (score 1):

To override the **user form** (when editing user profile) you can use `hook_form_alter` with `user_form` id.

On the following example code the `current_pass` is required so anyone making changes will need to enter it.  Also we assume that any administrator would not be forced to enter the password.

```
function MODULENAME_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) { 
  $user = \Drupal::currentUser()->getRoles();
  //admin's probably should not be forced to enter password 
  if(!in_array("administrator", $user) && $form_id == 'user_form') {
    //$form['account']['pass']['#required'] = TRUE;    
    $form['account']['current_pass']['#required'] = TRUE;    
  }
}
```

The **user register form** can be overriden with either one

```
function MODULENAME_form_user_register_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) { 
   //
}

function MODULENAME_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) { 
  if($form_id == "user_register_form"){
    //
  }
}
```

The module has to be enabled and/or the cache should be rebuild for the system to see those functions

Comment: the user_register_form_alter is working on my side. what I'm looking for is the hook alter the for editing user profile.

Comment: revised the answer please check